# Nested Solr Structure

Tags: solr, content-search

Is it possible to create a nested data structure in `Solr` using the content search index configurations? I'm curious if I can create a document like the following, then query against and/or facet the fields in the nested structure.

```
{   
    "_group":"fe58033195a142f7b33331d85e6120a9"
    "school_name_s": "School 1"
    "programs": [
        {
            "program_name_s":"Program 1",
            "program_type_s":"Program Type 1"
        },
        {
            "program_name_s":"Program 2",
            "program_type_s":"Program Type 1"
        },
        {
            "program_name_s":"Program 3",
            "program_type_s":"Program Type 2"
        }
    ]                
}
```

I'm currently using `Sitecore 10.1.0` and `Solr 8.4.0`

Comment: Can you provide an example of how your content currently looks in the index?

Comment: It looks like the example above (which has been simplified down), but without the nested programs field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short Answer

No.  You cannot create nested documents within Solr using the default Sitecore indexing functionality.

Since there's not a lot of background on the goals that you are trying to achieve, I can share some options that are available; each with their own benefits and drawbacks.  It'll be up to you to decide whether to implement any of these suggestions.

#### Option 1:

Use GraphQL (comes with Headless Services 16+) to query your parent and child documents together.

- https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/190/sitecore-headless-development/sitecore-graphql-api.html
- https://graphql.org/learn/

#### Option 2:

Create an index re-crawler that builds a new index using the nested document functionality.  There's documentation on how to do this in Solr here:

https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_4/indexing-nested-documents.html

This option does give you the ability to use BlockJoin faceting to search your documents and child documents.

https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_4/blockjoin-faceting.html

I've done this in the past, but some thorough consideration needs to be given to an update strategy on the new index.

**WARNING:** With the exception of in-place updates, the whole block must be updated or deleted together, not separately. For some applications this may result in tons of extra indexing and thus may be a deal-breaker.

#### Option 3:

Use a computed field to store your child documents as `json` within a `string` field.  This is quick and dirty and will get your content into the index, but you can't do any filtering, faceting or block joins on this field.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and thoughtful response Chet!